# Boostrap table not responsive

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, responsive-design

I'm doing a simple website using bootstrap. Right now, [image: I've a differents table] in which some information is inside.

I did check on the internet to see how to make this responsive, but so far nothing. Do someone have a link which can help me ?

Here is the code (which is a big long, sorry)

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center" style="color:#002D59">
            <div class="col-xl-7 col-lg-8 col-md-10 col-sm-12 mx-auto text-center p-4">
                <div class="mt-3 mb-3 text-center">
                    <nav class="nav nav-tabs">
                        <a class="nav-item nav-link active " href="#test1" data-toggle="tab">Test 1 tab here</a>
                        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#test2" data-toggle="tab">Test 2</a>
                        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#test3" data-toggle="tab">Test 3 here hey</a>
                        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#test4" data-toggle="tab">im here test 4</a>
                    </nav>
                    <div class="tab-content">
                        <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="test1">

                            <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th scope="col">ID</th>
                                        <th scope="col">Date of creation</th>
                                        <th scope="col">detail</th>
                                        <th scope="col">state</th>
                                        <th scope="col">comments</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th scope="row">1</th>
                                            <td>21/02/2020</td>
                                            <td>
                                                <div class="col-sm text-center">
                                                    <a class="btn btn-sm" href="#" role="button" style="background-color: #002D59; color: #FFFFFF; border-radius: 10px">
                                                        Link
                                                    </a>
                                                </div>

                                            </td>
                                            <td>description here</td>
                                            <td>comments over here</td>
                                        </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
```

The 3 others have the same code.

[image: Here is what is looks like after a little update]

Cordially

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `table-responsive` class to make a table responsive.

You can also use some CSS property to make table more responsive.

```
tr td {
    word-break: break-all;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
    max-width: 30rem;
}
```

Here it give all `td` to `max-width: 30rem` ( 1rem = 16px ) and allow to break word in content of your table.

```
tr td:nth-child(2) {
    min-width: 15rem !important;
}
```

after setting `max-width` all `td` automatically set its width but sometimes like in `email field` or `description field` you need more width so, you can set `min-width: 15rem` OR < any width > to specific `td`.

I hope the above steps will help you.

**UPDATE**

For making `nav-tabs` responsive you can use `flexbox`.

Here I used `flex-column flex-sm-row` two classes to make your `nav-tabs` responsive.

You can check those classes at https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/flex/

**WORKING EXAMPLE**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center" style="color:#002D59">
        <div class="col-xl-7 col-lg-8 col-md-10 col-sm-12 mx-auto text-center p-4">
            <div class="mt-3 mb-3 text-center">
                <nav class="nav nav-tabs flex-column flex-sm-row">
                    <a class="nav-item nav-link active " href="#test1" data-toggle="tab">Test 1 tab here</a>
                    <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#test2" data-toggle="tab">Test 2</a>
                    <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#test3" data-toggle="tab">Test 3 here hey</a>
                    <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#test4" data-toggle="tab">im here test 4</a>
                </nav>
                <div class="tab-content">
                    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="test1">
                        <div class="table-responsive">
                            <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th scope="col">ID</th>
                                        <th scope="col">Date of creation</th>
                                        <th scope="col">detail</th>
                                        <th scope="col">state</th>
                                        <th scope="col">comments</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th scope="row">1</th>
                                        <td>21/02/2020</td>
                                        <td>
                                            <div class="col-sm text-center">
                                                <a class="btn btn-sm" href="#" role="button" style="background-color: #002D59; color: #FFFFFF; border-radius: 10px">Link</a>
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>description here</td>
                                        <td>comments over here</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks ! One more thing, my onglet are looking really bad, there is a way to make it looks good ? (look at the originally post for the picture since I can't post a pic in a comment) Is it possible to make it as a dropdown or something else ?